# Can apache Heron be run on windows

Tags: java, windows, apache-storm, heron

I have been attempting to run a storm topology useing Heron which I believe is a relatively simple process. However, it seems there is no support for windows on the Heron site. Can I manually build Heron on windows or is it only supported on linux and OS X?

Answer (score 1):

Heron isn't supported on Windows, but you can deploy it on Linux and MacOS.

You can also try to use Virtual Technology tools such as [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) if you want run Heron on Windows.

[Here is my post](http://www.zhangyitian.cn/blog/setting-up-heron-with-aurora-cluster-locally-on-linux/) on setting up Heron with an Aurora cluster.

[This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47845464/how-to-deploy-a-twitter-heron-on-windows-os) on Stackoverflow might also help you.