# How to deploy a Twitter Heron on Windows OS?

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, heron

I can deploy a Twitter heron cluster on Liunx OS, but I don't know whether heron can be deployed on Window OS or not?

What's more, If I want to running a Heron project using IntelliJ IDEA, should I install the IntelliJ IDEA on Liunx OS(not windows OS?).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't support officially Windows yet for Heron. You can install the cluster in Linux and submit the topologies from Windows. If you find any issues, let us know - happy to resolve it.